# why do I get no output from zenity in shell script under gnome-schedule

Tags: gnome, rsync, zenity

I am using Fedora Linux 12, and intend to update to an up-to-date version soon. To prepare for this I have made a full backup on an external drive. I want to keep this backup up to date, using rsync, with the system described in: `http://webgnuru.com/linux/rsync_incremental.php`.

To schedule the backups I want to use gnome-schedule, and to output reassuring messages to my computer screen with zenity.

I am testing this on a small scale before I commit all my precious to it, and
here is a listing of my shell script. The updates work perfectly, so my question is: why do I get no output from the zenity command at the end?

```
#!/bin/bash
# Adapted from: http://webgnuru.com/linux/rsync_incremental.php
#  Website Backup Script
#======================================================================
# Define Variables
# Todays date in ISO-8601 format e.g. 2013-10-19:
DAY0=`date -I` 
# Yesterdays date in ISO-8601 format:
DAY1=`date -I -d "1 day ago"`
# The source directory:
SRC="/home/Harry/testrsync/bravo/"
# The target directory:
TRG="/home/Harry/testrsync/backups/$DAY0" 
# The link destination directory:
LNK="/home/Harry/testrsync/backups/$DAY1"
#The rsync options:
OPT="-avh --delete --link-dest=$LNK"
#======================================================================
#Execute the backup
rsync $OPT $SRC $TRG
#Delete old backups cyclically
# for my tests I am going to use a three day cycle
DAY4=`date -I -d "4 days ago"`
#Delete the backup from 4 days ago, if it exists
if [ -d /home/Harry/testrsync/backups/$DAY4 ]
then
rm -r /home/Harry/testrsync/backups/$DAY4
fi
zenity --info --text='Backup complete' --title="Backup Test"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer, after two days of struggling with arcane syntax and obscure references.

In the help document for Gnome Schedule it says:

```
9.2. Setting DISPLAY variable for tasks that will launch once

When you are creating or modifying a task, you can define the DISPLAY 
variable in the script text box. Make the definition at the beginning of the
script.

9.3. Setting DISPLAY variable for tasks that will launch recurrently

Gnome Schedule does not support yet setting environment variables for
recurrent tasks, but it will do soon. In the meantime, you can manually create
a script that first defines DISPLAY variable and then calls the graphical
application. Finally, you can create a recurrent task to launch the script.
```

Accordingly I created the script file `fred.sh` with the contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
DISPLAY=:0.0
#home/Harry/testrsync/trial_bak.sh
testrsync/trial_bak.sh
```

and used the script `fred.sh` as the scheduled task. I had named the test task script in my question `trial_bak.sh`. Note that the the script called from `fred.sh` must be referenced via the home directory, i.e. as the last line not the one commented out above. It now works and I get the desired information window pop up.

Note that this means that a "run once" preview in Gnome Schedule configuration may work, as it confusingly did for me, (I think it may use `at` instead of `cron`) but it needs to be tested as a recurrent task to be sure.

At first I added `DISPLAY=:0.0` to the last line of the script in the question, but found later that wasn't necessary

I used `xdpyinfo | less` to check what to use in `DIPSPLAY=...`, the `less` being needed because an awesome lot of information is churned out.

Finally, I have described what I discovered, and do not claim that it is definitive or complete, or even entirely correct. I would be interested in any relevant extra information that anyone can add,